# QGIS - using fill ring and snapping to segments not working

Tags: qgis, snapping, digitizing

When using the fill ring tool and having to run along the edge of the polygon the fill ring tool works perfectly when snapping to a vertex, but when I try and snap to a segment, which appears to work fine until you finish the fill ring and you get an error saying the ring was not contained in the feature.

What other option do I have to cut out an area of the polygon along the boundary of the polygon while still being offered the attributes table to name that new feature?

Comment: Which QGIS version is that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a long time ago, but I came across with the same question and I arranged a workaround for those who still might need it. The **fill ring tool** cannot intersect edges of polygons: it understands that there is still some piece of the original geometry left, and it leads to an error saying that the geometry is invalid.

To solve this, I used the **add part tool** instead, basically dividing the polygons into small areas. It works great with vertices and it snaps to the geometry with the **enable snapping tool** toggled on. Then I rearranged the information I needed using the attribute table.